# Adding series resistors to IC, increases input impedance?

Tags: operational-amplifier, impedance, digital-comparator

Does adding series resistors to a comparator / op-amp IC increase input impedance? Is this a right way to do?

[image]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you want to increase input impedance?

Comment: @Transistor -  I destroyed almost 4 lm311 IC’s. I thought due to excessive current. Now I have left only one MC3302p IC in hand. This one is working fine (I tested the just with as a comparator). I have an external circuitary to connect it. I am doing just on calculations (I don’t have any equipment like oscilloscope.

Comment: If you are destroying ICs, you probably have something connected incorrectly - show the circuit that is destroying the parts, and someone may bge able to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I think this is a classical XY problem. Your problem X is that your circuits blow up, but instead of asking about X, you think problem is solved by doing Y, increasing impedance, and are asking about Y, but Y might not solve the problem why the chips blow up.

Comment: @Justme - I know posting entire work here is a crime, I posted the entire circuit 9 days ago, results: “  Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers. “. What do i do ? That’s why I am solving each part separately.

Comment: Your question 9 days ago was actually closed because you refused to post the entire circuit. It can be reopened whenever you choose to do so FYI.

Comment: @user1850479 - I actually posted entire work of that project including some source URL’s, I don’t know why it is invisible to you ?.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Adding a series resistance to the input(s) increases the input impedance by the amount of resistance added.

The right way to deal with this is either buffer the previous stage so that the input impedance of the integrated circuit doesn't matter. Or, use a high-impedance input (FET) amplifier/comparator that is appropriate for your application or design.

Answer (score 1):

Op-amp and comparator input current is generally so small that it's acceptable, and sometimes even beneficial (to mitigate effects of input bias current, for example) to add a *small* resistance at an input, but by small I mean kilohms or tens of kilohms.

The input impedance most op-amps or comparators, including older devices, exceeds 10<sup>7</sup>Ω, and almost all modern devices are over 10<sup>9</sup>Ω, with the exception I'll describe in a moment.

This means that you would have to add many, many megohms of resistance in series with an input in order to compete with input impedance that's already there. Excessive resistance will degrade the performance of the op-amp considerably, so that all those impressive datasheet specifications such as low input offset voltage, or high bandwidth are lost, and you end up with something that can't even compete with an LM301 from the 1960s

It's much more likely that you are destroying devices by applying input potentials beyond the bounds of the power supplies.

Many devices have input protection diodes, whose purpose is to divert electrostatic discharge current *around* input circuitry, rather than through it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVm4J4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If somehow you apply \$V_{IN} > V_{CC}\$ or \$V_{IN} < V_{EE}\$, then one of those diodes is forward biased, and becomes almost a direct short circuit to a power supply node. This can result in significant current flowing through that diode, into/from the supply rail. That causes heating, and can damage the device.

Any device with such diodes will tell you how much current will destroy the device. For example, from the [TL071 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl072h.pdf):

[image]

Under "signal input pins", "current", see ±10mA. That's how much current can flow via an input without damage. Any more than that is enough to kill the thing.

Devices that don't have such protection, are even more vulnerable to input potentials beyond the supplies. Always check the datasheet to find out the acceptable input voltage range.

Your proposed solution, to add resistance in series with an input, is actually common practice, but as I mentioned, that resistance is usually only a few kilohms. An example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fANgLW.png)</sup>

\$V_{IN} = +30V\$ is applied to the inverting input, which significantly exceeds the +15V supply, resulting in current that takes the red path, towards the lower potential. Diode D1 develops about 0.3V, leaving 14.7V across resistor \$R\$. Therefore, by Ohm's law, current \$I\$ is:

$$ I = \frac{V}{R} = \frac{14.7V}{2.2k\Omega} \approx 7mA $$

The resistor in this example limits the current entering/leaving the IC's input to below 10mA, so if this were a TL071, it would be safe. It would be damaged if that current exceeds 10mA, which would still happen if \$V_{IN}\$ were to exceed some maximum:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{IN(MAX)} - 15.3V &= IR \\ \\
V_{IN(MAX)} &= 10mA \times 2.2k\Omega + 15.3V \\ \\
&= 37V
\end{aligned}
$$

By all means, add a small resistance to protect the op-amp inputs from excessive current, but this will only be of use if you expect that the input potential may extend beyond the power supplies.

Don't just add any old resistance, find out what the expected maximum and minimum input potential could be, and calculate a resistance to suit.

All this does is protect the device from damage. It doesn't guarantee good behaviour from the op-amp/comparator. There are other input voltage constraints. From the same [TL071 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl072h.pdf), parameter \$V_{CM} = \pm 11V\$ (with ±15V supplies). That means good behaviour of the TL071 is not guaranteed for inputs closer than 4V to the supply rails, but such inputs will not cause damage.

<sub>If losing 4V of acceptable input range at each end sounds like poor performance, that's because it is. The TL071 is well known for this caveat. Some TL071 variants do better, but in general it's pretty much useless for supplies less than ±6V</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It increases input impedance from the perspective of your signal source, however, it does not provide the benefits of a high impedance input since the impedance is not integral to the input transistors. As far as the input transistors are concerned, those resistors belong to your signal source so you get all the downsides associated with that.

So you don't load down your signal source as much, but you muck with the signal when it arrives at the input transistors to be read, so it's pointless.